# Set horizontal bars according to the numerical vector

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to set my bars according to the vector I am providing. The vector is the substitution for the names.arg funciton used to name the bars. What I want to achieve is: I want to plot my bars in order that I am providing (similar to the histogram ordering). The goal is to get the bars being plotted according to the vector and not at equal intervals.

From the example here I should be getting the most of the bars on the Left hand side oppose to be evenly spaced as they are now.

```
a = c(1,2,6,8,11,2,3)
b = c(-0.2, 0.1, 0.12,0.13,0.2,0.5,0.6)
data = cbind(a,b)
barplot(data[,1], names= b, col =rgb(0,200,0,50,maxColorValue=255))
```

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear. What is it you're trying to do? What's the intended output?

Comment: When I plot the barplot on its own the the bar names (names.args) are only the names for each plot. I want to be able to manipulate the axis and preferbly to set in the range between -0.2 to 0.6 in 0.2 intervals. So that the bars that correspond to those points adjust accordingly

Comment: If I understand you correctly you wish to put your bars at positions given by `b`. I don't think it is possible to set an `at` argument with `barplot`, i.e. "numeric vector giving the locations where the boxplots should be drawn" (see `?boxplot`).

Comment: Yeah I was trying to specify the marks through the sequence, and then applying the at function to go by those labels, but nope :(. Any suggestion what I can use ?

Comment: I wanted something like this 
http://foss.gauravsmind.com/2011/11/r-bloggers-is-wonderful-site-which.html

Comment: @pops, I have posted a `ggplot` alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to your question before the edits, i.e. how to plot *horizontal* bars with a location determined by a numeric vector. As I wrote in my comment, `barplot` in `base` does not have an `at` argument, i.e. a "numeric vector giving the locations where the boxplots should be drawn" (see `?boxplot`).

Here is a `ggplot` alternative. In `ggplot` data have to be in a data frame. x and y axes are swapped (make x vertical, y horizontal) using `coord_flip`. I also set the previous x values (a) as y values, and vice versa for b. Set `expand` to zero to remove the margin between the 'bottom' of the bars and the axis.

```
df <- data.frame(a = a, b = b)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = b, y = a)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           width = 0.03,
           alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: @pops, since my answer refers to your _original question_ with horizontal bars (which I assume was the problem you really wished to solve), you may consider editing back your question.

Comment: yes that was the problem I was trying to solve. I have reviewed the original post. Thank you by the way!